# GTX680 GPU BIOS OverClock stuck to 1150MHz

Tags: bios, gpu, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

I started to overclock my GTX680 by editing its BIOS. Problem is that the Boost Clock is stuck at 1150MHz at full load even though I set the Boost Clock to 1228MHz, then 1254MHz and finally 1280MHz.

Screenshot from GPU-Z: [GTX680 OverClocked BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am568.gif).

I noticed that when I open MSI Afterburner and unlock voltage control I can crank the voltage to +12 (max). If I do that the core clock will raise to 1163MHz. That's still much less than it should be. If I let the voltage to zero and raise core clock I can raise it to 1254MHz (can't remember what the offset was). I wanted the gpu to boost up to 1254MHz because I tested that it's stable enough and at 1228MHz it never crashed. How do I manage to get those numbers through BIOS?

Settings in BIOS:

TDP Base Clock: 1058.5MHz
3D Base Clock: 1058.5MHz
Boost Clock: 1280.5MHz
Boost Limit: 1280.5MHz
Memory Clock: 3505MHz
Voltage: 1225.0mV - 1312.5mV (Too scared to raise more)
Max Table Clock: 1280.5MHz

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I manage to get it working!

Problem was those Entrys (#0-2), there was same Entry (#1) for TDP and 3D Clock. I changed TDP to use Entry #1, 3D to use Entry #2 and Boost to use Entry #0. Then I changed 3D clock to 1280MHz and that's it.

Now it runs smooth at 1280MHz and boosts it down for a while when not needed.

So actually, the only problem was the user which wasn't so super.